# Cardinality: Is the last sum correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, polynomials, rational-numbers

We have the set $A=\{a_1, a_2, \ldots \}$, the $a_i$'s might be finitely or infinitely many. 
We have that $\mathbb{Q}(A)=\left \{\frac{f(a_1, \ldots , a_n)}{g(a_1, \ldots , a_n)} : f,g\in \mathbb{Q}[x_1, \ldots , x_n], g\neq 0, a_1, \ldots , a_n\in A,  n\in \mathbb{N}\right \}$.

We have that $\mathbb{Q}(A)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}P_n$ where $P_n$ is the set of all polynomials of $\mathbb{Q}(A)$ of degree n. $P_n$ can be represented as a $(n+1)$-tuple of the rational coefficients.

It hold that $|P_n|=|\mathbb{Q}^{n+1}|=|\mathbb{Q}|$.

Then we have the following:

$$|\mathbb{Q}(A)|=|\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}P_n|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|P_n|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\mathbb{Q}|$$

Is the last sum correct?

Comment: What are the $a_i$? Real numbers? Rational numbers? Integers? Something else? What is $S$? What is $Q$? The same as $\mathbb Q$ or something else?

Comment: $S$ was a typo, it is $A$. $Q$ must be $\mathbb{Q}$. @celtschk

Comment: That still leaves the question of the $a_i$.

Comment: There is no other information about $A$ other than it is finite or counitable. And we the $a_i$'s are either finitely or infinitely many. @celtschk

Comment: Ahh... We also have that $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q}(a_1, a_2, a_3 , \ldots )\subseteq \mathbb{C}$. @celtschk

Comment: Then the terms $f(a_,\ldots,a_n)$ and $g(a_,\ldots,a_n)$ (and thus $\mathbb Q(A)$) seem not to be well defined, as two arbitrary mathematical objects in general have no addition or multiplication between them defined. There *must* be something said about the $a_i$ (or the set $A$) for the question to make sense.

Comment: We also have that $S$ is a trancendental basis of the extension $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q}$. We also have that $|S|< \mathfrak{c}$. Does this help? @celtschk

Comment: With $S$ you mean $A$, again? Well, in that case it does help insofar as it (probably) makes the question well-defined, but it also means it's beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064050

Comment: A countable union of countable sets is countable. Each $P_n$ is countable so $\cup_{n\in \mathbb N}P_n$ is countable.

Comment: Why is each $P_n$ countable? @user254665

Comment: A member of $P_n$ is determined by its sequence of $n+1$ rational co-efficients, so it is determined by a member of $\mathbb Q^{n+1}.$... If $S$ is  a finite set of countable sets then $\prod_{t\in S}t$  is countable.

Comment: I got stuck right now... How do we use the last sentence with the product? @user254665

Comment: Let $J_{n+1}=\{j\in \mathbb N: j\leq n+1\}.$ Let $Q_j=\mathbb Q \times \{j\}.$ So$ P_n$ is countable if $\mathbb Q^{n+1}$ is countable if $\prod_{j\in J_{n+1}}Q_j$ is countable.  Now each $Q_j$ is countable, and $\{j:j\in J_{n+1}\}=J_{n+1}$ is finite.

Comment: @Mary Star: you wrote "$P_n$ can be represented as a $(n+1)$-tuple of the rational coefficients". That's why a (finite, actually $n+1$-fold) product is needed here.

Comment: I haven't understood where we need the product? Could you explain it further to me? @tillmo

Comment: Elements of $P_n$ can be represented as $(n+1)$-tuples of the rational coefficients. Hence $P_n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^{n+1}$.

Comment: And therefore, we have that $|P_n|=|\mathbb{Q}^{n+1}|=|\mathbb{Q}|$, right? @tillmo

Comment: Do we have then also that $|\mathbb{Q}(S)|=|\mathbb{Q}|$ ? @tillmo

Comment: 1) yes, 2) yes if $|S| \leq |\mathbb{Q}|$, i.e. $S$ is countable.

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!! :-) @tillmo

Comment: Having that $S$ is a trancendental basis of the extension $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q}$, why do we have that $|S| \leqslant \mathfrak{c}$, where $\mathfrak{c}$ is the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$, and not $|S| \geq \mathfrak{c}$ ? @AsafKaragila

Comment: Since $S\subseteq\Bbb C$, the cardinality of $S$ is at most $\frak c$, then an argument is needed to show that it is at least $\frak c$ in order to get equality.

Comment: I see!! It is given as a hint, the proposition: If $E/F$ is an algebraic extension, then $|E|=\aleph_0\cdot |F|$. Why does this hold? Is every algebraic extension infinite? @AsafKaragila

Comment: Algebraic extensions of $\Bbb Q$ have surjections from $\Bbb Q[x]$ onto them. So they are countable.

Comment: So, this doesn't hold for every extension, just for $F=\mathbb{Q}$ ? @AsafKaragila

Comment: It holds for all infinite $F$. If $F$ is finite, then it need not be true, since it could have *finite* extensions.

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you!! :-) @AsafKaragila